# Is DMA write/read with respective to memory or device?

Tags: memory-management, dma

Recently I have heard several version of DMA write/read operations, and I didn't have any luck searching google. Some claim it's device-centric while some say it's memory-centric. When people usually say DMA write, is DMA write to the device or device write to memory? Thanks for clarifying the convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you an empirical example !
I have had validated a PCIe based DMA in past. This PCIeDMA was a module of the slave device that was connected over PCIe bus to the x86 host. The slave device had a memory of 800KB. In our case 'DMA Write'meant - The DMA reads the data from the memory of slave device and transfers/writes it to the host memory and vice versa for 'DMA Read'.
Hope this clears your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of gross oversimplification . . .

In a DMA system, the device can access memory just as the CPU[s] can. Or you can view the devices as being just another processor.

In your terms, usually it is writing to memory.